# Playing audio tracks through S/PDIF or Toslink with track marks

Tags: audio, music-player

I recently got a MiniDisc recorder and I'd like to put some music on it from my PC (running Arch).

Back in the old days, one could copy CDs over to MD or DAT by hooking up a CD player to a recorder through S/PDIF or TOSLINK. The audio stream would come out of it with embedded track marks that told the recorder to advance the track count so one doesn't have to split an entire album into tracks by hand later.

Is there any Linux audio player out there that is able to play a batch of audio files (or a *.cue/*.bin pair) while placing track marks between them, just like a CD player, DAT or a MiniDisc would do?

Comment: Don't know any player, but note you need an ALSA `iec958` device (or Pulseaudio "passthrough") to be able to send raw S/PDIF data. Track marks for CD players are specified in IEC 60958-3](https://archive.org/details/gov.in.is.iec.60958.3.2003), so if necessary, you can write a simple player that outputs those ...

Comment: Did you find such a player? What sort of sound card are you using or intended to use?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. No specific soundcard on my mind; My intent was to use built-in Toslink output on my motherboard.
I since got another, NetMD recorder which can download music onto a minidisc over USB, but it's still not ideal since original software is weird and awful, and opensource linux-minidisc software is somewhat unstable at times...